# Identificar cambio de dispositvo en php

Tags: php, login, app

estoy desarrollando una app en php, y necesito que la app me identifique si el usuario accedio a la app desde otro dispositivo.

Como ejemplo enviar un correo al cliente  : Hemos detectado un inicio de sesion desde otro dispositivo si fuiste tu no contemples este mensaje, si no fuiste te sugerimos cambiar la clave.

Me quedo atento a sus comentarios

Comment: Menos mal que quedas atento a los comentarios, porque primero, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so], segundo, te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Lamentablemente tu pregunta es demasiado abierta, como si pidieras opinones y sugerencias. En [es.so] respondemos preguntas que plantean un problema específico, que podamos reproducir mediante un [mre]. Te invito a leer el [help/on-topic] donde se expone el tipo de preguntas aceptables en el sitio. Además, en el mismo [help/dont-ask] se expone el tipo de preguntas que debes evitar. Lamentablemente tu pregunta terminará cerrada. Saludos

Comment: Tu pregunta es muy ambigua. Antes de realizar una pregunta en stackoverflow procura haber indagado soluciones. Por lo general, en esta comunidad se responden preguntas especificas. Como dijo Mauricio, procura leer¿Como preguntar? en la seccion de ayuda de Stackoverflow

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.